# Debugging at evaluation

Tags: java, debugging, jvm

Is it possible, when evaluating an arbitrary expression, say in IDE evaluation dialog, to have the execution stopped on breakpoints?

Say I evaluate myClass.myMethod(), which I have a breakpoint set in, and the breakpoint is hit.

If it's possible at all, I guess it's a JVM matter, not IDE. Any ideas?

Comment: It's an IDE matter, unless you're writing an IDE. If you *are* writing an IDE then you do need to know how it works in the JVM.

Comment: You've heard of JUnit/TestNG etc right?

Comment: @immibis I'm not a developing an IDE. Any ideas which IDEs provide such feature? Idea seems to lack it

Comment: @Kong how are testing frameworks related to this?

Comment: No idea which IDEs allow this.

Comment: @meliniak - if your using a modern IDE (IntelliJ, NetBeans, Eclipse...) you can set a break point in your code; run a unit test through the IDE and step through. This is vs "just running the app".

Comment: @immibis How do you know it's IDE responsibility then? My guess it's a kind of JVM limitation, like when breakpoint is hit, due to it's internal peculiarity, another breakpoint cannot be hit.

Comment: @Kong yeah sure, but I need full server application context, like database connections and so on.

Comment: @meliniak - ahh; yep. And why does a unit test stop that? And it sounded like you wanted to test a small expression?

Comment: @Kong I need to have all spring stuff up and running, with server-defined jndi datasources and so on. so it won't be easy to have that set up in junit. the thing I want to test depends on a database. no matter what I wanted to test, I just asked about the jvm/debugger behaviour, not testing methodology.

Comment: @meliniak - I know you need the full environment, that's just a given. I can post you some of our unit tests that need a Spring context if that would help? Just to clarify - your question is "how do I test (and step through) xyz" when xyz is build up from a Spring context? If that is what your after I can help.

Comment: @kong I'm often in need of debugging a method, which cannot be called directly via user gui interaction. So what I do then is just hit any breakpoint and try to evaluate it via:

org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes().getRequest()).getBean(MyComponent.class).myMethod()

but that way, breakpoint are not stopped on. That why I asked this question. Anyway, thanks for your involvement.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Spring. Then you've probably bought into the whole [Martin Fowler et al Layering](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) pattern.

I'm using IntelliJ and JUnit, so adapt to your needs.

I have a base class at the root of each of my IntelliJ modules (layers) test roots:

```
/**
 * An abstract base class that other tests can inherit from to 
 * get spring functionality.
 */
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/spring-config-domain.xml"})
public abstract class SpringAwareTest {
}
```

Your tests can then simply extend that to be "context aware".

```
public class NavigationServiceTest extends SpringAwareTest {
    @Autowired private NavigationService service;

    @Test
    public void folders() throws IOException {
        List<Folder> folders = service.getFolders(TestConstants.USER_ID);
        Assert.assertNotNull("Folders is null", folders);
    }
```

Build up each of your layers (modules) with higher level tests, for example at the Service layer:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/spring-config-service.xml"})
public abstract class SpringAwareTest {
}
```

And import the lower level layers in your Spring config files (which you need to do in your app for real anyway):

```
<import resource="spring-config-dal.xml"/>
<import resource="spring-config-security.xml"/>
...
```

Now you can set break points and step through to your hearts content; all with a full context.

If you just want to test something (or step through) a piece of code that doesn't require a context. Then just test it as per normal (don't extend SpringAwareTest). That will be much faster as it doesn't need the lag of bringing up the context. This starts to matter when you move to Continuous Integration aka Jenkins etc.